# Android app crashes on starting new activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

When I click on a button (called chooseDistance) I simply want to start another activity, this I believe is working, however I have an if statement to check if a value is not null before this activity can start, this I believe is working as when I click the button it does not start the activity if the value is null. I have included the activity in the manifest file. I cannot find the error in my code below:

setdestination.class:

```
package com.example.drivetext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class setdestination extends Activity implements OnMapLongClickListener {

        private GoogleMap map;          
        Location myLocation;
        TextView tvLocInfo;
        LatLng pointfinal;
        ListView listview;
        ArrayList<String> distancesendList;
        String finaldistance;
        String contactNo;
        String message;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.setdestination);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            contactNo = intent.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");
            message = intent.getStringExtra("TextMessage");
            Toast.makeText(this, contactNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                

            ListView distanceList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);


            distancesendList = new ArrayList<String>();
            getdistances();
            // Create The Adapter with passing ArrayList as 3rd parameter
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, distancesendList);
            // Set The Adapter
            distanceList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); 

            // register onClickListener to handle click events on each item
            distanceList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
               {
                        // argument position gives the index of item which is clicked
                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v,int position, long arg3)
                       {

                               String selecteddistance=distancesendList.get(position);
                               finaldistance = selecteddistance;
                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Distance Selected : "+selecteddistance,   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
               });

            tvLocInfo = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locinfo);

            FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            MapFragment myMapFragment = (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            map = myMapFragment.getMap();

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            //myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            map.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);

            Button chooseDistance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnchooseDistance);
              chooseDistance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {              
                 public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     if (finaldistance != null)
                     {
                         Intent intent3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), targetdistance.class);
                         intent3.putExtra("PhoneNumber", contactNo);
                         intent3.putExtra("TextMessage", message);
                         intent3.putExtra("Coordinate", pointfinal);
                         intent3.putExtra("SelectedDistance", finaldistance);
                         startActivity(intent3);
                     }
                     }
              });
        }

        void getdistances()
        {
            distancesendList.add("100");
            distancesendList.add("250");
            distancesendList.add("500");
            distancesendList.add("1000");
        }

        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
            tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));
            pointfinal = point;
            Toast.makeText(this, point.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
   }
```

my targetdistance.class:

```
package com.example.drivetext;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class targetdistance extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.target);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String cNumber = intent.getStringExtra("PhoneNumber");
    String txt = intent.getStringExtra("TextMessage");
    String coord = intent.getStringExtra("Coordinate");
    String seldis = intent.getStringExtra("SelectedDistance");

    Toast.makeText(this, cNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, coord.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Toast.makeText(this, seldis, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

}

Lastly my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.drivetext"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyCvVY0OSaoe6Y_MfpP2S6HZQpXT5jtUwMQ"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.drivetext.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".setdestination" android:label="Set Destination"> </activity>
    <activity android:name=".targetdistance" android:label="Target Distance">       </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

target.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your logcat please

Comment: I am uploading file using google drive as Samsung Galaxy S5 is not recognised with Eclipse, even with all the correct drivers installed.

Comment: Does that mean you have no logcat? can we have target.xml layout plz?

Comment: The `"Coordinate"` extra is not a String. You should use `getParcelableExtra()` to retrieve it.

Comment: I changed it to what you said and updated the variable type also to LatLng and it now works. Thank you.

Comment: so did we verify that you don't have a logcat? there really should be one if you excpect to get an answer. 
That being said map fragments are notorious for crashing because locations can be null.